# Mega Menu items not getting clickable and links not navigating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am facing an weird issue, I have integrated the mega menu from https://codyhouse.co/demo/mega-dropdown/index.html

But the Category and sub category links are not getting clicked and not navigating to the links. I believe that might be some restriction in Js or Jquery.

Here is the site I am talking about http://puunnamiifashhions.com/punami/index.php

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It works for me

Comment: but its not redirecting to the links, can you let me in which browser are you testing it ? I am checking in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: I mean, in this page http://puunnamiifashhions.com/punami/index.php, you have a button called Categories below the logo, when you click on it the categories toggle down and sub-categories come on hover.. I am talking about those items.. they are not navigating.

Comment: @AnilNaidu chrom Version 60

Answer (score 0):

you need to user `event.preventDefault()` in jquery to prevent default behavior of `<a>` tag

read more here:[jquery preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

in your problem i think this script work:

```
   $('p.close-menu a').click(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
   });
```

above code in javascript is:

[read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
document.querySelector("#id-checkbox").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     document.getElementById("output-box").innerHTML += "Sorry! <code>preventDefault()</code> won't let you check this!<br>";
     event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: I am using this Jquery file, can you please guide me where can I add the given code  ?

Comment: I used this comment in the view file as <script>
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( "<div>" )
    .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
    .appendTo( "#log" );
});
</script> but still now use